# parent-child sync with system-v semaphores

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore

I am having a function that prints something char by char in a loop. What i'm trying to do is syncrhonize a parent and child processes so that each print a line without having the other interfering. I am trying to do this with semaphores.

this is my code:

```
int main() {   
  int i, sem;   
  struct sembuf u   = {0, 1, 0};   
  struct sembuf d = {0 -1, 0};   
  sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0600);   
  semctl(sem, 0, SETVAL, 1);

  if (!fork())   {
      for (i=0;i<10;i++){
          semop(sem, &d, 1)) < 0)
          print_char_by_char("hello\n");
          semop(sem, &u, 1);
      }



  } else {
      for (i=0;i<10;i++){
          semop(sem, &d, 1);
          print_char_by_char("world\n");
          semop(sem, &u, 1);
      }


      semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

So this is not working, the prints are garbled and i'm really not sure why. Also if i put a check on `semop` like this:

```
if((x = semop(sem, &down, 1)) < 0)
    perror("semop");
```

i am getting `semop: File too large`

Answer (score 0):

According to [man semop](http://linux.die.net/man/2/semop)

> EFBIG: for some operation the value of sem_num is less than 0 or
>   reater than or equal to the number of semaphores in the set.

Then, without knowing how is your `print_char_by_char` function, we can't know why you get garbled print (remember that `printf` and others are buffered, so you should use `fflush` next, or directly use `write` instead.

By the way, I tried to execute your code (which I wrote below) and I don't have any problem (because you didn't specify what output do you expect) if I remove the

```
semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);
```

that maybe you misplaced (should go just before the `return`, otherwise the one who finishes first will remove the semaphore set, I guess)

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

void error_handler(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <no arguments>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int i, sem;
    struct sembuf u = {0, 1, 0};
    struct sembuf d = {0, -1, 0};
    sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0600);
    semctl(sem, 0, SETVAL, 1);

    if (!fork())
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (semop(sem, &d, 1) == -1)
                error_handler("main | semop [d - father]\n");
            if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, "hello\n", 7) == -1)
                error_handler("main | write [hello]\n");
            if (semop(sem, &u, 1) == -1)
                error_handler("main | semop [u - father]\n");
        }
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (semop(sem, &d, 1) == -1)
                error_handler("main | semop [d - child]\n");
            if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, "world\n", 7) == -1)
                error_handler("main | write [world]\n");
            if (semop(sem, &u, 1) == -1)
                error_handler("main | semop [u - child]\n");
        }

        // semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
world
world
world
world
world
world
world
world
world
world
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

Instead, if you wanted to synchronize two processes in a father-child relationship (this sounds weird...) I'll suggest you shared memory and POSIX semaphores